# Why telnet works directly from command prompt but not with open command

Tags: telnet, windows-server

When I use following command in command prompt then it works:

`telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 443`

But if I open telnet client from command prompt and then try following command from withint telnet then it doesn't work. Why?

`open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. 443`

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: In 2nd case no error is shown. It just remains stuck at connecting and control is not returned.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What happens if you use `open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +443`? And `open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx +443`? Is this the same for all hosts you try connect to?

Comment: OS is Windows 2016 standard. Using + with port number doesn't help either. Same issue

Comment: While not answering your question, `telnet` shouldn't be used as it's insecure and there is no way to secure it _(everything is passed in plaintext, including passphrases)_ - SSH would be recommended.